# Does github (twitter, stripe & co) uses oauth for its own login?

Tags: authentication, oauth

Does github (twitter, stripe & co) uses OAuth for its own signin/signup forms?

All those authentications are cookie based, so is this regular web client basic auth or does it use some form of OAuth or xAuth ?

On login, a call to https://github.com/session (or https://twitter.com/sessions or https://dashboard.stripe.com/ajax/sessions) is made (with credentials given as formdata) that result in a 302 (or 200 for stripe) with `Set-Cookie` and a location to https://github.com (or https://twitter.com).

It does not seems that they use a `client_id` to get a `code` and exchange it with a `token`. All the OAuth dance seems striped. And the Bearer header too. So, what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth
check the security section

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is a three-legged system, two-legs is sort of useless.  The whole point of using OAuth is to give other services the ability to perform actions as you without needing to specifically authenticate or pass the data yourself.  In the end you must still authenticate against some Auth service.

Since you are using these services as the Authentication mechanism for other sites, it wouldn't make sense to attempt to use it in your own.  As part of setting OAuth, the second site redirects to the first and asked to authenticate there, which means you literally need to enter your credentials.  Which means that if you are okay entering your credentials into say github, having a different authentication mechanism is useless.

OAuth allows non-github to create user accounts by trusting github with the authentication, or it allows non-github sites to make changes to github as the user once the user agrees to the interaction by logging into github to accept that policy (logging in using their credentials).

Comment: Totally agree with you about OAuth doing authentication delegation for other services. So the website authentication mechanism (classic login / pass) is not related in any way to OAuth? It probably may use a basic auth, don't you think?

Comment: It looks like github is just using encrypted formdata and then saves the result as a cookie (probably the most common).  Since websites can save cookies, and I see the `Cookie` header in the request, that is most likely how the data is being sent (not using an auth header, and at that point the auth mechanism can be anything).  Bearer specifically refers to a particular auth type, but since websites can auth however the like because you are literally passing in your username:password, the result just has to be a session token.  I assume they just validate the token when they get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in forms on github (and others websites as well) are simply cookie based.

Usually every direct login via the website through a browser is made with cookie based system , simply because isn't necessary to do otherwise.

### A bit of theory

Every time you use a login form in a website you are calling an API, not necessarily intended for public use (so a **private** API)

When you put your credentials in the login form and push that login button , your credentials are being managed by some code in the server that permits you to authenticate against that website.

There is no need for the entire OAuth overhead here because the website has full control on the authentication mechanism and isn't necessary to externalize.

### Why OAuth is different in this contest?

OAuth is a system designed to distribute the authentication system across different services / applications even from different vendors.

In OAuth there are multiple actors involved:

- the client
- the authorization server
- the resource provider

In your case all these 3 actors are the website itself and so there is no need for a decoupling system like OAuth.